# Firestore Get value from dynamic key field or from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem retrieving a value from Firestore where my field key it's dynamic.

I have this code for add new fields to my DB:

```
db.collection('programacio')
    .doc(idSetmana)
    .set(
        {
            [id]: valor
        },
        { merge: true }
    )
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Document successfully written!');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Error writing document: ', error);
    });
```

But when I can't get this id value from a variable. For example, if I have this code:

```
db.collection('programacio')
    .doc(id)
    .get()
    .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            var cell;
            var numFiles = $('#tbody_programacio tr').length;
            var numColumnes = 5;
            for (let i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
                for (let j = 1; j < numColumnes; j++) {
                    cell = 'fila' + i + 'columna' + j;
                    var hola = doc.data().cell; <<<<<<< Cell doesn't work because isn't a field's name
                }
            }
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log('No such document!');
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error getting document:', error);
    });
```

Can I get value from a key name from a variable?

If isn't possible, my objective is save every cell from a table to my DB and when I click on that cell return the DB value, but I don't know if it's possible with another way...
Thanks for all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `[]` (bracket) notation:

```
var hola = doc.data()[cell];
```

Comment: Oh it's perfect! It works! This had not occurred to me!